# Determine, with proof, all polynomials $P(x)$ such that, $P(x)P(x+1)=P(x^2)$, $P(X)$ is belonging to $R[X]$

Tags: polynomials

Determine, with proof, all polynomials $P(x)$ such that, $P(x)P(x+1)=P(x^2)$

Put $x=1$ into this equation, we can get $P(2)=1$
and put $x=0$, we can get $P(1)=1$
$x=-1$, $P(-1)P(0)=P(1)$

Then what should I do, just simply calculate the product of $P(x)$ and $P(x+1)$? So confused.

How to do the multiplication for these 2 polynomials and determine the $P(x)$.

Comment: Multiplying those gets you a really complicated expression, which is almost of no use unless you bring the degree of the polynomials down. Note that apart from literally multiplying them, you can also substitute different values of $x$.

Comment: Special values of $x$ that are worth considering are 0, 1, -1, and the zero-points of the polynomials.

Comment: Yeah, I realised this, but how to determine the value of P(0)?

Comment: You don't need to determine $P(0)$, although it may be a rational step to try when solving this problem

Comment: You find that if $P(0) \ne 0$, $P(1) = 1, P(2) = 1, P(0)=1/P(-1), P(3) = P(4), \dots$ by plugging several values. Maybe at some point this gives the desired system. Note that the expression of a $n$ degree polynomial is entirely determined by $n+1$ points.

Comment: I find the description in the question confusing. Why is it working with three different lists of coefficients, $$a_n,a_{n-1},...\\b_n,b_{n-1},...\\c_n,c_{n-1},...$$ All other parts of both question and comments seem to imply there should only be one set so that $P$ denotes the same polynomial throughout, right?

Comment: Yes, just P(X).

Comment: What field is your polynomial defined over?

Comment: All Real Numbers!

Comment: Sorry, I should edit this.

Answer (score 6):

Hint. The given identity holds also for any complex number.
Note that if $z$ is a complex root then also $z^2$ is a complex root, which implies that $z=0$ or $|z|=1$ (otherwise we have infinite distinct roots). In a similar way, if $z$ is a complex root then also $(z-1)^2$ is a complex root, which implies that $z-1=0$ or $|z-1|=1$.

So what are the possible roots of $P$? The answer will give you a  factorization of $P$.